# Office 365. Spill functions functionality

Tags: office365, office-js, excel-addins

I saw that all methods related to the spill functionality are in the preview mode (e.g. hasSpill, getSpillToRange, etc). When do you plan to deploy them to production?
[Official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.range?view=excel-js-preview#hasspill)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `range.hasSpill` and `range.getSpillToRange` are in our plan to release in 1.12 at Ignite conference. If there is no big bug found before that, you would be able to see this API GA at Ignite.

Comment: Hi @RaymondLu! Have the range.hasSpill and range.getSpillToRange been released in 1.12?

Comment: yes, please refer to  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.range?view=excel-js-preview#hasspill